# How to add a "Message sent" message on top of the page that is shown after form submission (it is not being shown now)?

Tags: php

How to add a "Message sent" message on top of the page that is shown after form submission (it is not being shown now)? Here is the php file:-

```
    <? ob_start(); 
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$email = "dr_ramanand@rediffmail.com";
$subject="Quick Response";
    
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($_POST['name'])."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($_POST['phone'])."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($_POST['email'])."\n";
    
    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($_POST['address'])."\n";
    
    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($_POST['subject'])."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($_POST['comments'])."\n";
    $email_message .= "Keywords: ".clean_string($_POST['keywords'])."\n";
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$from_email."\r\n";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From     = "dr_ramanand@rediffmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Cure4incurables";
$mail->Subject =  $subject;
$mail->Body    = $email_message;
$mail->AltBody = "";//$text_body;
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if(!$mail->Send())
{
}
header("location: https://www.cure4incurables.in/Contact_Us.html");//echo "Message Sent!"; 
?>
  <? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: This is the url of where the enquiry form is hosted : http://cure4incurables.in/enquiry.html

Answer (score 2):

the easiest thing to do would be to add a GET Variable to your target location and change this target file from html to php:

```
header("location: https://www.cure4incurables.in/Contact_Us.php?sent=1");
```

in Contact_Us.php you can then do

```
if (isset($_GET['sent'])) {
 echo "Thank you for contacting us";
}
```

Comment: just adding `?sent=1` adds a GET Variable to the target location right? I did what you said and even created the Contact_Us.php file and added the matter you told me to but the message, "Thank you for contacting us" is not getting displayed after the form submission! For your information, I am not a developer.

Comment: can you post the content of Contact_Us.php please or at least the first part and the part including my script? As a sidenote: Be careful when using upper and lower case letters in your filenames. Unix systems are case sensitive, while Windows systems are not. While not necessary, I recommend using only lower case letters for filenames as it often leads to errors, when you don't be extra attention

Comment: Have you uploaded that script with the change? Because when I submit the form with the link you've posted, I get forwared to Contact_Us.html, not Contact_Us.php?sent=1. And in your form (enquiry.html) replace the `http` here `<form method="post" action="http://www.nitamicrotek.in/forms/cure4incurables/submit.php" onsubmit="return verify()">` with `https` to send the form over a secure connection

Comment: I got a professional to do it. Thanks for trying to help anyway!